# CMake: Modifying library output directory of a target from a sub-project

Tags: cmake

I have a top-level CMakeLists.txt which includes another third party project from a subdirectory, like

```
add_subdirectory(ext/third_party/cmake)
```

`third_party` contains a library target which I want to build, but I want to modify some properties and want to avoid to modify the original CMake file. I do *not* want to link some of my own targets to that library, I'd rather want that third party library to be build with some modified properties and then put it into a custom output directory. So I do

```
set_target_properties(libthird_party PROPERTIES
        # some properties that successfully get applied here
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/my/output/dir")
```

I can see that other properties are successfully applied and the build is modified to my needs correctly, but the generated output library is not put into the directory I set. What could be the reason for that?

If this is a totally wrong or bad approach please also feel free to propose a better approach for my goal.

Comment: There several `*_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` properties, each of them affects only on a specific type of the build artifact. E.g. `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` affects on `.so` libraries on Linux but doesn't affect on `.dll` libraries on Windows.

Comment: Interesting to hear that. In my case I'm especially trying to affect the directory for a static linked `.a` MacOS lib. What's the correct property for that and where do I find an overview of the correct properties to set here?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out myself with help from the comments. I was trying to modify a static library target, which is not affected by `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` (which only applies to dynamic libraries) but which needs the setting `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`. So the corrected call is

```
set_target_properties(libthird_party PROPERTIES
        # some properties that successfully get applied here
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/my/output/dir")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to deal with `[LIBRARY, ARCHIVE, EXECUTABLE] x [Single, Multi]config generator x [Unix, Windows]way`.

note: On Windows everything (.dll, .exe) is on the same directory while on Unix you generally have a `bin` and a `lib` directories.

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

# Single config (e.g. makefile, ninja)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
if(UNIX)
 set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
 set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
else()
 set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
 set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
endif()

# For multi-config build system (e.g. xcode, msvc, ninja-multiconfig)
foreach(OUTPUTCONFIG IN LISTS CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  string(TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG)
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} 
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
  if(UNIX)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} 
      ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} 
      ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
  else()
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} 
      ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} 
      ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
  endif()
endforeach()
```